# How to store sessionStorage as a variable so it can be stored in a database

Tags: javascript, php

I need to store the email of a logged in user, which I have stored into 
sessionStorage with the line of code:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("loggedInUser", $("#email").val());
```

But in a different program, I need to store the email as something so that it can be sorted and posted to a php file that inserts it into my database. Here is my javascript so far.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //When the submit button on the recruitment form is pressed.
        $("#SubmitRecruit").on("click", function () {
                //store each individual entry into a separate variable.
                var email = sessionStorage.loggedInUser;
                var forename = document.getElementById("forename").value;
                var surname = document.getElementById("surname").value;
                var jobType = document.getElementById("jobType").value;
                var phoneNo = document.getElementById("phoneNo").value;

                //create an array with the details in.
                var recruitdetail = {
                    email: email,
                    forename: forename,
                    surname: surname,
                    password: password,
                    phoneNo: phoneNo,
                }
                //log the forename in the console so that we know that the register has been successful.
                console.log(email)
                //direct the user to the login page and alert them that their registration was successful.
                window.location.href = "../index.html"
                alert("Your recruitment post was made, thank you. We will get back to you shortly.")
                //posts the JSON object to the php file so it can fill the database, and converts the register array into JSON so it can be read. 
                var jqxhr = $.post("../php/recruit.php", JSON.stringify(recruitdetail)

                )
            }
        })
```

On the 5th line I tried to make it equal to sessionStorage.loggedInUser with no avail. I know I need to store email as something from session surely, as then it will be passed back into php and stored in db, but I cannot figure out what or how to do this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just submit the form to server  and do the redirect there?

Comment: I am submitting the form to the server, this just stringifys the data for the php file. but I do not know how to get the email into the php because it is also a foreign key so I cannot just have the user enter one into the form.

Answer (score 0):

To get the item from session storage try using the getItem method:

```
var email = sessionStorage.getItem("loggedInUser");
```

See [sessionStorage documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

For the ajax request, just pass the object directly to `$.post` and put the alert in the success callback so it only shows when the request completes successfully:

```
//posts the JSON object to the php file so it can fill the database, and converts the register array into JSON so it can be read. 
var jqxhr = $.post("../php/recruit.php", recruitdetail, function(data) {
    alert("Your recruitment post was made, thank you. We will get back to you shortly.")
});
```

As a side note - if you have a table of users/logins, the email of each user should stored in that table. The foreign key between your users table and other tables would then be an (auto-incrementing) ID, rather than an email address. This makes the system much more flexible (email can be changed, etc).

Comment: hi, this didn't work. i click the submit button and it says successful but just doesnt go into my database

Comment: @DylanWade There could be something wrong with your php code. What does the "Network" tab in dev tools (inspect element) show when you submit it? Click the request when it goes through and look at the Request Payload data in the Headers tab, and then the Response tab.

Comment: my javascript is there on the network tab, but my php file isn't? I do not know why... Is there any way I can contact you to show you what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use local storage with our array, we'll need to convert our array into a string using a method that makes it easy for us to unconvert later. The way convert an array into a string is by using the JSON stringify function.

Let's say you have the following array called movies:

var movies = ["Reservoir Dogs", "Pulp Fiction", "Jackie Brown", 
              "Kill Bill", "Death Proof", "Inglourious Basterds"];
Using the stringify function, your movies array can be turned into a string by using the following syntax:

JSON.stringify(movies)
Since we want to store everything into our local storage, when you put it all together, you get the following:

var movies = ["Reservoir Dogs", "Pulp Fiction", "Jackie Brown", 
              "Kill Bill", "Death Proof", "Inglourious Basterds"];

localStorage.setItem("quentinTarantino", JSON.stringify(movies));

Comment: OP is storing a string (email) in session storage, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

If by different program you mean different application on different domain, then you can try sending the email value through an AJAX request to be stored in the PHP session.

If on the same domain but just a different app running in a different tab, then you can use `localStorage`, with the same syntax as `sessionStorage`. Note that `sessionStorage` data is limited to the tab in which it was set.

```
localStorage.setItem("loggedInUser", $("#email").val());
```

and then

```
        var email = localStorage.loggedInUser;
```

Or you can use cookies. 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: both programs are javascript